# Symfony2 get path info of URL explicitely

Tags: php, symfony, pathinfo

Say, I have an URL `http://server/mysite/web/app_dev.php/resource/1`.
I am doing a `GET` request and the corresponding action is `ResourceController::getAction`.

In this controller action if I call `$request->getPathInfo()`, it gives me `/resource/1`.

But in the same controller if I create a Request object with a url of another resource and call `getPathInfo()` it returns a longer version.

```
$request = Request::create('http://server/mysite/web/app_dev.php/another_resource/1');
echo $request->getPathInfo();

OUTPUT >>
/mysite/web/app_dev.php/another_resource/1
```

How is it possible to make `getPathInfo()` to return only `/another_resource/1` in this case?

### OR

Anyone can suggest what is the safest way to convert an endpoint URL `http://server/mysite/web/app_dev.php/another_resource/1` to `/another_resource/1` in Symfony2?

#### In case you are interested to know why I need this

The controller action is receiving some URLs in request content. The action needs to parse those URLs to recognize the corresponding resource. I am trying to make use to `$router->match` function to retrieve the parameters from the URL. The match function expects only `/another_resource/1` part.

Comment: You can try getting the base url from your current `Request` object with `$request->getBaseUrl();` and use it with `str_replace` for instance, and replace it with an empty string with the one returned by `getPathInfo()`. This is a bit of a hacky way. I could write an answer later why you get a different output when using `::create()`.

Comment: Thanks @Artamaiel. This approach can definitely solve the problem as long as the baseurl doesnt change. However, I will still look for something else that will work even the base url is changed like switching to `app.php` to `app_dev.php` etc. I really want to forget about the baseurl part. Currently I am planning to put a prefix for all of the endpoints and my url parser service will split the url by that prefix. In this way i am gonna strip out the unwanted part. Not so elegant solution either but at least with this approach I dont really need worry about the `baseurl` part at all.

Comment: `I could write an answer later why you get a different output when using ::create()`, please do. It would be certainly a useful thing to know in this context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Request::create method create a new request that don't know any information about current request, it return full uri because it not know current script file.
try:

```
$request = Request::create('http://server/mysite/web/app_dev.php/another_resource/1', null, array(), array(), array(), array(
    'SCRIPT_NAME' => $this->get('kernel')->getEnvironment() == 'dev' ? 'app_dev.php' : 'app.php',
    'SCRIPT_FILENAME' => $this->get('kernel')->getEnvironment() == 'dev' ? 'app_dev.php' : 'app.php',
));
echo $request->getPathInfo();
```